# Not having any luck with :hover, either with jquery or css

Tags: css, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

Neither seem to work right for me. Starting with query:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button1").hover(function() {
$("#button1").animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
});
});
</script>
```

This causes the opacity to shift down, but it doesnt resume on mouseleave. Jquerys hover page says to put a in and out action like so:

.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )

so when i do this it just gives me both animations on mouse in and again on mouseout:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button1").hover(function() {
$("#button1").animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500),
    $("#button1").animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
});
</script>
```

So i gave up on that and tried mouseenter/mouseleave combo:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button1").mouseenter(function() {
$("#button1").animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500); 
});
("#button1").mouseleave(function() {
$("#button1").animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
});


</script>
```

It just sticks on the mouseenter animation. So i tried the css method:

```
<style>
a:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
<div>
<a id="button1" ><img src="Assets/button.png"></a>
</div>
```

Doesnt do jack. :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nm, i give up. The only way ive gotten mouse events to work is by putting it directly within the element (onmouseup: onmousedown: etc...). I did get a:hover to work finally but theres no way to animate it without cutting out ie9 and below, so thats out of the question. At least theres a solution, no thanks to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the hover handlers in separate functions, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button1").hover(function() {
        $("#button1").animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $("#button1").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500)
    });
});​
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I have this script posted at the bottom of the body, below the button element, could that cause a problem? Im using jquery 1.7.2 in FF11, maybe one of them broke the :hover and :mouseenter/leave function?

Comment: Only if it's not embedded in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: no, its in a script tag. Is this working for you? This is my code:                                                                 <img src="Assets/button.png"  id="button1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; z-index:999999;" class="button" />                                                                           <script>
$(function() {
    $("#button1").hover(function() {
        $("#button1").animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $("#button1").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500)
    });
});​
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jQuery, but the CSS example you've provided works perfectly for me. I just copied code from the example and swapped the image with one of my own.

Consider checking whether your browser (it's version) fully supports opacity. I'm using Firefox 12.0

Comment: This is my entire markup in a new page, nothing happens (posting head and body separately)                                                                                                                                  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
`

Comment: `<body>
<img src="Assets/button.png" id="button1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; z-index:999999;" class="button" />
 <script> $(function() { $("#button1").hover(function() { $("#button1").animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 500); }, function() { $("#button1").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500) }); });​ </script>
</body>
</html>`